# How to add error bars to bar graph when the outcome variable is binary in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to plot a main effect of a factor ('emotion', 3 levels) on an **binary outcome variable** ('cr') using [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot)in [r](/questions/tagged/r).

```
#computing mean and sd
    data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
      require(plyr)
      summary_func <- function(x, col){
        c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
          sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
      }
      data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                      varname)
      data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
      return(data_sum)
    }

     sophie1 <- data_summary(sophie, varname="cr", groupnames ="emotion") 
     head(sophie1) 



    base_plot <- ggplot(sophie, aes(x = emotion, y = cr)) +
      stat_summary(aes(fill = factor(emotion)), fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", color = "black") + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("#3182bd", "#636363", "#e6550d")) +  # colorbrewer2.org
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme_bw() +
      xlab("Emotions") + ylab("Pr (correct response)")+
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=cr-sd, ymax=cr+sd), width=.2,
                    position=position_dodge(.9)) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
    print(base_plot)
```

and I get this error message:

```
Error in cr - sd : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To get the standard deviation as an errorbar you can do `stat_summary(aes(fill = factor(emotion)), fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "errorbar", color = "black")`.

Comment: hello, this gives a graph without bars but with error bars ; but I would like both

Comment: You're still running the first call to `stat_summary` where you generate the bars?

Comment: Yes you need both `stat_summary` calls.

Comment: Yes!! Actually, `fun.data = mean_cl_normal` was what I was looking for!! thank you